# Use of undeclared type 'NSXMLElement' error

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, swift2, xmppframework

I searched a lot and found it:

```
func getAllRegisteredUsers() {
    do {
        var query: NSXMLElement = try NSXMLElement(xMLString: "<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/>")
    } catch { }

    var iq: XMPPIQ = XMPPIQ.iqWithType("get", to: XMPPJID.jidWithString("DOMAIN"), elementID: xmppStream.generateUUID(), child: query)
    xmppStream.sendElement(iq)
}
```

but it returns me that

```
Use of undeclared type 'NSXMLElement'
```

Is there any other ways for getting all users list or how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DDXMLElement instead.